# Charge Payload different to Cart total (rounding)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, checkout

I have isolated the reason why zip pay orders are cancelling on our system with the help of their support.

### This is the response from the integrations team.

We have taken a look at the issue and it seems the issue occurs on your end and only when an order has 2 decimal places or more.

The reason the error is occurring is that there seems to be rounding on your end before we create the charge.

The reason this only affects Zip orders is that Zip checks to see if the order details match what is being passed to Zip and if it doesn't throw an error to ensure the customer is charged the correct amount.

Below you can see the product page which rounds to the nearest first decimal:
 (product shows price as $2180)

​

And below you can see the cart page which doesn't round:
(shows price as 2179.98)
​
Zip takes the cart page information then compares this to the charge payload before creating the charge.

You can see below that the charge payload is rounded after the checkout which is causing the error:
 (picture of code with charge as 2180)
​

You can also compare this to the checkout response below which has a different value:
(picutre of code with charge as 2179.98)
​

We aren't sure if there are any business rules applied on your end which is causing the behavior, however, the Zip plugin is functioning as intended.

I would recommend speaking to your developer as this doesn't seem to be the standard Magento rounding and it is causing the issue when charging the customer.

---

I am using OnePage checkout and can only think that this is the place causing issues.

Any suggestions on how to stop this from happening (ie stop it rounding after checkout on the charge payload)?!

I am happy to try anything.

Cheers

Comment: You can round off price for the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was not simple.  For some reason in our store the onepagecheckout was rounding to 4 places and the store was rounding to 2 places.

It was a matter of forcing all prices to round to one value.  I ended up using an extension to achieve this and it worked.  I know us zip, after, and paypal all in one happy environment.